Why would op-amp shoot up to positive rail during power on?
Here is a PSpice simulation on an ISL70419SEH with the +/-15V power supplies ramping up:



The output voltage is starting out negative, then shooting up to where the positive rail is at, then going down to zero. What is the reason for this? I've contacted the manufacturer to see if there is something glitchy with their pspice model, but I haven't heard back. Is this likely just some glitch or is there a real physical reason we would see the op-amp behave this way on power-up?

There's no expectation of the op-amp behaving itself when you violate the conditions for normal operation such as minimum supply voltage or input common-mode range.
Minimum recommended supply voltage is 10V (+/-5V) and input voltage range is only to within 2V of each supply rail with 5V supplies. So two sets of conditions are violated.
At a 1V supply it might do any number of things. I wouldn't expect the model to accurately simulate what happens under those conditions (though it might depending on how the model was constructed). It's not usual for an op-amp to go to one rail or the other when the input range is exceeded. In some cases, a transient condition can cause the entire circuit to latch up in some undesired state- some op-amps are more prone to this and you'll find it discussed under the umbrella of "phase reversal" or "phase inversion".
Also, I doubt your ramping of voltages symmetrically is realistic unless you've deliberately implemented some very special circuitry- usually one rail comes up before the other.
Anyway, if this sort of transient condition can cause problems, you might need to add additional circuitry to supress the output until the supplies are in range and stable, or otherwise make the condition benign.

The op-amp is rated to work from 4.5V upwards, or +/- 2.25V.
In your case, with approximately +/- 0.5V supplies, the op-amp does not have to work properly and anything can happen.
The datasheet Circuit 1 explains that the input is a NPN stage with current-source pull-down. It might be that the input pull-down source starts first at lowest voltage, and shortly after it can also start outputing signal, but still it won't yet work properly due to extreme undervoltage.
Or it's a simulation glitch.
It is also unrealistic to expect anyone to answer your question why the op-amp simulation works like this, unless you are a paying customer with enough money and a real-world problem with the chip. They cannot spend 1h pay on a hobbyist that generates no revenue, compared to say some company or space agency that buys these rad-hardened op-amps by the thousands each year via sales reps and FAEs.
